# Wrapping a .NET WCF service proxy class in a USING { } block?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

Quick question, but is it best practice to wrap a service proxy class in a using statement? Meaning, in VS, we generated a proxy for a WCF service. For the service class, should it be wrapped in using? I don't believe it implements IDisposable and there is no Dispose() method. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although proxies generated by Service Reference and svcutil.exe *do* implement `IDisposable`, in general it is *not* a best practice to wrap them in a `using` block; instead favor explicit open and closing.

Why? Well, the problem is that the `Dispose` method calls `Close`, *which can throw* in various circumstances, most prominently if the channel is in a Faulted state. In general this is bad, but if this happens during a finally block because you let a fault exception bubble up, it could swallow the original fault exception in favor of the `Close` exception, effectively losing the original exception.

Comment: Usually, I don't explicitly open and close. I usually initialize the service and invoke methods on it - never actually closing upon completion. I see this a lot too. Bad practice?

Comment: @Ryan Peters: if you're using a `using` block, that wouldn't be bad practice, other than the issue I mentioned. But you should always close your channel when you're not using it, either explicitly or implicitly. Explicitly *opening* the channel, on the other hand, isn't always necessary, as the first operation call on the proxy will always open the channel.